# Why is web page not available and returning error Unsafe_resirect?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView in my Android application. My WebView loads a web page. This web page sends call to another URL but this call returns Webpage not available.

First webpage in my WebView is loading fine. But when I click on buttons on first web page, it sends request to another webpage for some processing but the second webpage is returning Web page not available with Error `Unsafe_resirect`. It is working fine on iOS and Web. This issue only exists in Android.

In my custom WebView client, I am getting response in `onReceivedError` instead of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`:

I am using:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(context));
 webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
```

My URL and `postData` are confidential, so I can't share them.

Comment: Please add some code sample

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: To handle your situation, where the application uses confidential data, you should create a minimal app sample reproducing the issue with non-confidential data and then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your redirect URL is not HTTPS so it is blocked on newer Android versions. You can try to set `usesCleartextTraffic` to true in Manifest ([Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic))
or add custom Network Security Configuration ([Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config))

Comment: My redirecting url is HTTPS, It's secure